# Can you use using to redeclare a public member in base class as private in derived class?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, using, using-declaration

This code snippet demonstrating changing class member access came from [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.cbclx01/change_access_class_member.htm).

```
struct A {
protected:
  int y;
public:
  int z;
};

struct B : private A { };

struct C : private A {
public:
  using A::y;
  using A::z;
};

struct D : private A {
protected:
  using A::y;
  using A::z;
};

struct E : D {
  void f() {
    y = 1;
    z = 2;
  }
};

struct F : A {
public:
  using A::y;
private:
  using A::z;
};

int main() {
  B obj_B;
//  obj_B.y = 3;
//  obj_B.z = 4;

  C obj_C;
  obj_C.y = 5;
  obj_C.z = 6;

  D obj_D;
//  obj_D.y = 7;
//  obj_D.z = 8;

  F obj_F;
  obj_F.y = 9;
  obj_F.z = 10;
}
```

According to the article, modifying `obj_F.z` is allowed because the `using` declaration in the `F` class does not take effect, and therefore, `F::z` is still `public`.

However, when I plug this into [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/SMMt88), it does not compile, saying `F::z` is `private`. What's going on here?

Comment: The `using` does not affect access of an inherited `public` member when inheritance is `public`.   Putting the `using` into a `private` section of a derived class does not make the member `private`.   If you want to make members of a base class `private` to a derived class, use `private` inheritence.   The name `F::z` is private member of your class `F`, but `A::z` is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article seems wrong. It says,

> You cannot restrict the access to x with a using declaration.

But I can't find such statement from the standard. [[namespace.udecl]/19](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/namespace.udecl#19)

> A synonym created by a using-declaration has the usual accessibility
>   for a member-declaration.
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
> class A {
> private:
>     void f(char);
> public:
>     void f(int);
> protected:
>     void g();
> };
>
> class B : public A {
>   using A::f;       // error: A​::​f(char) is inaccessible
> public:
>   using A::g;       // B​::​g is a public synonym for A​::​g
> };
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Even the example is increasing the accessibility, but the standard doesn't say accessibility can't be restricted.

PS: Both [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ba1irQ1ViG2gccXE) and [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3frDJFSH74sNj0M7) fail to compile the code.